# changing the shape of the button in mailchimp

Tags: button, mailchimp

im using the mailchimp plugin for wordpress and struggling to work out how to change the code to make the edges of the submit button round. So I don't want it completely a circle, just rounded edges?

Also keen to change the font colour and font (to a google font) for Name and Email address and the agreement text.

Any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please read How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your attempt, example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: I have tried a few options but dont have a useful code to share..